# kate editor, shortcut to close/move current tab

Tags: ubuntu, editor, kate

`kate` editor (default `kate` package on Ubuntu 14.04)

- Is there a shortcut to close current tab (from multi-tab plugin)?
- Is there a way to move around tabs (move current tab forward/backward relative to other tabs)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For closing current document try **Ctrl+W** or **Ctrl+Esc**
- I am not sure about moving tabs around but try **Alt + →** and **Alt +←**

Comment: The second shortcut does help to move the focus, but not actually move the tab. Anyway looks good thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Moving of tabs is currently not supported. There are feature requests to add this behavior back, but we didn't come around to implement it yet (I'm one of the Kate developers).

ALT+left, and ALT+right focus the prev/next tab (horizontally)
ALT+up, and ALT+down focus the next document in the Documents list (vertically).

To close a tab, indeed choose CTRL+W.

Comment: good to know thanks. Kate is my favorite editor, great to here from one of its developers. Looking forward to the new features.